# Feather identification

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image: Unknownfeather]

One of my sister's chickens was killed a few days ago.  This feather was left at the scene of the crime.  The location was Idaho, near Boise.
The death of the chicken leads us to believe it is a hawk or falcon but the vertical brown line has us all scratching our heads.  The current belief is it's from a juvenile, but we can't pick out the type.

Does anyone recognize it?

Comment: please add a bit more information like the size of the feather and what time of day/night was the chicken killed and what injuries did it have any information can help identify the bird.

Comment: Certainly.  The feather is 5 inches long.  The chicken was killed in the afternoon, the sun was still above the horizon.  While I didn't see the carcass, I was told it looked like it had been pecked over and over.  Likewise, she owns a very large, very grumpy rooster who was missing some feathers and had his comb ripped, meaning it had to be big enough to take on a large, angry rooster who was trying to defend.

Comment: perhaps try the feather atlas https://www.fws.gov/lab/featheratlas/idtool.php, or reddit/birdwatching reddit birds of prey it's too specialized for here

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say definitively from a picture, but the feather looks very much like that of a Barn Owl (*Tyto Alba*). This also fits with the geographic location of Idaho.

Take a closer look at the trailing edge of the feather, it appears to have the soft "fluffy" edge typical of most owl feathers.

Here's an example that shows the similarity:

https://www.barnowltrust.org.uk/barn-owl-facts/signs-barn-owl-occupation/signs_feathers-male-female/